# Delphi Pop Up Box With Image

Tags: image, forms, delphi, button, popup

So I'm new to Delphi and I have a button and when it is clicked it opens an OpenPictureDialog. I then want to create a popup box with that picture loaded into it. I'm not sure what the best approach to this would be?

I was thinking to make a new form on the button click event and then put the image into that, but I can't figure out how to pass a TImage to a form constructor.

```
OpenPictureDialog1.Execute;
img.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
TForm2.Create(Application, img).Show;
```

Does anyone have a better idea of how to do this or a way to fix what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You better put the TImage component in your secondary form and pass a filename, for example, create a new constructor for your form like this:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
  private
  public
    constructor CreateWithImage(AOwner: TComponent; AImgPath: string);
  end;

...
implementation
...

constructor TForm2.CreateWithImage(AOwner: TComponent; AImgPath: string);
begin
  Create(AOwner);
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(AImgPath);
end;
```

Then, you can create and show your form like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form2: TForm2;
begin
  if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Form2 := TForm2.CreateWithImage(Self, OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
    Form2.Show;
  end;
end;
```

## Edit

If you want to create the image at runtime, you can do it like this:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    FImage: TImage; //this is now in the private section, 
                     //and not the default (published)
  public
    constructor CreateWithImage(AOwner: TComponent; AImgPath: string);
  end;

...
implementation
...

constructor TForm2.CreateWithImage(AOwner: TComponent; AImgPath: string);
begin
  Create(AOwner);
  FImage := TImage.Create(Self);
  FImage.Parent := Self;
  FImage.Align := alClient;
  FImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(AImgPath);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an elegant solution, however I'm having a problem. "raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 00403B27 in module"    If I comment out the ImageLoad line it runs fine though.

Comment: You must create objects in delphi before you use them. `variable = TForm2.Create(Application, img);  variable.Show;` - If Image1 is NULL then you didn't DROP the IMAGE on the form visually you just typed code. You can't just write a line of code in a form declaring a variable without creating it.

Comment: I put in a call to Create for the image variable and still get the same error.

Comment: Drop it on the form, don't create it.

Comment: Interesting Warren P, that worked. I'm not exactly sure why though? What does dropping it on the form do that I wasn't doing by creating a variable?

Comment: @user it does nothing different. If you drop it in design time, at runtime Delphi create it, set the parent and set the properties stored in the DFM, how do you created it?

Comment: Components dropped onto a `TForm`, `TFrame`, or `TDataModule` at design-time are creating automatically at runtime for you.

Comment: @user loot at my edited answer, it shows now how to create the TImage at runtime.

Comment: I can't get it to not throw the error when I do it the 2nd way.

Comment: @user1970794: The simple way is to drop it on the form. Creating visual components from code is a more advanced technique that I do not recommend to someone who has less than a few weeks experience in  Delphi, until you have first mastered "how to walk around without hitting the furniture", I suggest you do not try "to run a marathon".

Comment: @user Listen to Warren in the first place, but the code I put in my edit works very well. Your's is the same?